# Ancheer 250watt Motor Hall Sensors?

Tags: sensor

I need to replace  the 3 hall sensors in this 36v 26" hub motor for ancheer bike.
I purchased the 41F/0H41/SH41/SS41F/S41 Bipolar Hall Element Sensor TO-92UA
but it is bigger and does not fit. i squeezed them in to make them fit but they dont work. motor does not respond to these they are the wrong model. anyone can suggest which hall sensors might work. the originals are lableled 4010 1724
and nothing like this exists online. ancheer also doesnt know.

Comment: Have you tried electronics.stackexchange?

Comment: Have you tried Ancheer ?   Why do all three sensors need replacing ?

Comment: It's going to be hard to determine which hall sensor you need if you have no idea what the characteristics of the ones you're replacing are (also, how do you know that the sensors need replacing?)

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need digital hall sensors (instead of analog versions). Most bldc motors use digital hall sensors. You should check your controller specs to see what type of hall sensors it supports but most likely you will need digital.

have you tried testing the hall sensors with either a multimeter or controller tester to see if they  switch on and off when rotating the wheel? Are you sure your hall sensor leads are correctly connected to the controller? Is there voltage on to the GND and +5V wires going to the hall sensors? (Measure voltage across these two wires when the controller is turned on, the motor doesn't have to be moving for this.
Are you sure you didn't damage your hall sensors during installation?

Is there any other text/marking(brand perhaps) on the original hall sensors? Could you attach a/some photo(s) of the original hall sensors for reference?